# Which is the latest source code?

Tags: android

This is my first post to this group. I am looking at the screenrecord.cpp source code from android.googlesource.com. I found the following source links for the screenrecord.cpp file.

1. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.4.2_r1/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp
2. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/aaa3f358410701710e31f31de62f0b4521989661/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp

I think, #2 link is the latest source code for screenrecord.cpp. However, how can I know which source code is the latest one?

Any idea would greatly help me.

Comment: You can see it using the file history which is present just after the blob path

Comment: Yes looking at the history the second one seems to be the new one. 
If you have access to the GIT.Try to merge your files first. Do a git status to see what are the files that need to be merged (means you need to resolve the conflicts first). Once this is done, do git add file_merged and do your pull again.

Comment: Yanivx, yes, by looking at blob path only, I said #2 link is the latest one. However, is there a method to find the exact date of the each file that is uploaded into the git - Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you mean by "latest".

The currently-shipping version of Android, "KitKat" 4.4.2, comes with version 1.0 of screenrecord.  That's what your first link points to.

The "master" branch of the AOSP source tree has the sources for screenrecord v1.1, which adds some new features.  That's your second link.  The newer version can be built and run on Android 4.4, but it's not checked into the 4.4 branch, so no devices I'm aware of currently ship with it.

Details about v1.1 are [available here](http://bigflake.com/screenrecord/).

Answer (score 0):

To see the latest in any git tree, you click on the link higher up the tree.

So for both the link you provided, click on higher up link and you will notice ending up here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master

Within the page is also indicated the latest commit number, and that is the latest as of anytime you are reading this article.

And then travelling down the link to reach the screenrecord.cpp again:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp

now you notice that this link does not have any version anymore, but is tagged with a commit number - not at the link itself, but the first few lines of the page.   That page is also the latest in development right now.